# Return error 500 in laravel query when I use get()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, get, http-status-code-500

I use this laravel query in my code :

```
        $teamRoles = TeamMembers::where('is_active',config('constants.status.enable'))
           ->get();
        dd($teamRoles);
```

I don't know why this result return HTTP ERROR 500 but when I use ->find() or ->first() instead of ->get() that works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was for php memory size; I change memory_size in php.ini and it solve.

Comment: Are you fetching all(at least 1000 or more) records at once? If yes, I am afraid, this isn't the correct way. You may want to paginate them.

Comment: @vivek_23 yes that's not the correct way but that was at first in my query and I didn't set other conditions yet.